# Android app to record the path and speed while driving

Tags: android, logs, maps, gps, car

I am looking for an Android application that can record the path, as well as the speed at each point of the path when I drive.

For example, the Android app [RunKeeper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper.pro&hl=en) can do it for jogging:

[image: RunKeeper screenshot]

Any price is good.

Comment: Can't you just use it as is? I mean, just drive instead of run? However, I want to let you know about strava (which I actually use for tracking workouts), which has a bycicle category that might suit your case better, and runtasic, which has even more categories, but I am now sure about driving. There is also gpsies.

Comment: Let me ask a stupid question, Franck: wouldn't any GPX recording app do? Each recorded type has a timestamp associated, so it should be easy to calculate the speed between them. Or do as Marcel suggested, and use runkeeper while "running your car" :) Not owning a car I never cared about this specific need; but as usual, I've got a [list of tracking apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_tracking) you might wish to check while waiting for answers :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have stated, there are any number of apps that could do what you require to a greater or lesser degree, including Runkeeper itself.

After trying several, the one I have settled on is [Cycledroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maral.cycledroid&hl=en).

As the name suggests, it is aimed at cyclists.  However, it exports the information that you require in GPX or KML format.

It doesn't try to match your performance with others (like Strava), so you don't upset cyclists by beating their segment records by 50mph.  It has a simple interface, uncluttered by calorie counts and similar, which aren't relevant to driving.

Answer (score 1):

#### OsmAnd with the Trip Recording plugin

The Android app I use for recording trip data when driving is the excellent [OsmAnd](http://osmand.net/) with its [Trip Recording plugin](http://osmand.net/features?id=trip-recording-plugin).

> The Trip Recording plugin allows you to record your trip and save it
>   as a GPX file. It uses your phone's GPS to track your movement. You
>   can view the route you've travelled, send it to OpenStreetMap project
>   or upload it to external services.

That would be an all-in-one solution since you could use just one app for your (offline) map viewing, navigation, POIs and trip recording, all based on OpenStreetMap and Wikipedia data. It is not specific for driving, it can be used for activities such as running, walking, cycling, etc..

Some of the data recorded:

- Distance
- Start time
- End time
- Time span
- Time moving
- Average altitude
- Descent/Ascent
- Average speed
- Maximum speed

The app is open source, actively developed and it's available in two versions: [OsmAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand) (free) and [OsmAnd+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand.plus) (paid). With the paid version you support the project, fund the development of new features, and receive the latest updates (you can get an unlimited number of map updates). **The Trip Recording plugin works fine with both the free and paid versions.**

Here are three basic screenshots from the website:

[image: Trip recording]